# Удаление элемента из вектора с помощью erase

Tags: stl, vector, c++

Есть такой код(Обычный алгоритм Крускала):

```
void read_from_file(const char* file_name)
{
    ifstream inf(file_name);

    inf >> count_town >> count_road;
    graph.resize(count_town);

    int from_, to_, weight_;

    while (!inf.eof())
    {
        inf >> from_ >> to_ >> weight_;
        from_--;
        to_--;
        edges.push_back(make_pair(weight_, make_pair(from_, to_) ) );
    }

    inf.close();
}

//все вершины графа
vector <int> marks;

void change_mark(int mark1, int mark2)
{
    if (mark2 < mark1)
    {
        int t = mark1;
        mark1 = mark2;
        mark2 = t;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < count_town; i++)
        if (marks[i] == mark2)
            marks[i] = mark1;
}

void cruskal_algo(vector<pair<int, pair<int, int> > >& tree, vector<pair<int, pair<int, int> > >& edges)
{
    marks.resize(count_town);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < count_town; i++)
        marks[i] = i;
    sort( edges.begin(), edges.end() );

    remaining_edges = edges;

    int k = 0;
    int t = count_road;
    int i;

    while (k < count_town - 1)
    {
        i = 0;
        while ((i <= t) && (marks[edges[i].second.first] == marks[edges[i].second.second]) && (edges[i].first != 0))
            i++;
        k++;
        pair<int, pair<int, int> > p = edges.at(i);
        tree.push_back(p);
        vector<pair<int, pair<int, int> > >::iterator it = find(remaining_edges.begin(), remaining_edges.end(), p);
        remaining_edges.erase(it);
        change_mark(p.second.first, p.second.second);
    }
}
```

Граф задан списком рёбер с именем `edges`.
`Edges` - это вектор пар. Первое значение в паре - это вес ребра, второе значение - пара - первое значение - первая вершина ребра, второе значение в паре - вторая вершина ребра.
Всё это дело(дерево минимальное) записывается в `tree`.
Еще я хочу найти список оставшихся рёбер, не вошедших в дерево.
Список оставшихся рёбер - `remaining_edges`(имеет такой же тип как edges и tree).
Я просто-напросто взял скопировал в `remaining_edges` вектор `edges` и получил копию `edges`.
Далее, в строках

```
vector<pair<int, pair<int, int> > >::iterator it = find(remaining_edges.begin(), remaining_edges.end(), edges[i]);
    remaining_edges.erase(it);
```

я нахожу в копии edges, т.е в `remaining_edges` элемент `edges[i]`(то, что добавили в дерево)
и удаляю его из `remaining_edges`.
Но проблема в том, что здесь

```
remaining_edges.erase(it);
```

выдаёт ошибку

> "vector erase iterator outside range"

Вроде бы ошибка тривиальная, но у меня уже битый час не получается её исправить.
Спасибо.

Comment: Для начала, для удаления из вектора используется не erase, а пара [erase/remove](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom).

Comment: @rekrut1: Можете предоставить _минимальный_ код, воспроизводящий проблему?

Comment: Вот, я добавил код. Читается файл, в котором граф задан рёбрами с весом:

`7 8
1 2 1
1 3 6
2 3 3
2 4 12
4 7 4
4 5 5
5 6 2
7 6 7`

в первой строке файла содержится кол-во вершин(в коде - count_town) и кол-во рёбер(count_road).
Дальше идут рёбра с весом начиная со второй строки в файле.
Первое число - начало ребра, второе - конец ребра, третье - вес этого ребра.
Граф неориентированный.

Comment: @rekrut1: А можно и вправду **минимальный** пример? Уберите `read_from_file`, задайте что, что нужно, в коде. Обязателен такой большой граф, или на меньшем тоже воспроизводится? Нужна ли часть `cruskal_algo` до цикла while для того, чтобы воспроизвести проблему? Нужен ли сам цикл? Укоротите пример до 5 строчек, оставьте только нужное.

Answer (score 2):

Вы проверяете `it != remaining_edges.end()` ? Возможно, `std::find` ничего не находит и вы пытаетесь удалить элемент по итератору, указывающему **за** конец вектора.

Comment: как раз таки find находит то, что нужно.
Даже ptr указатели совпадают.

Comment: @rekrut1 Каким образом совпадают указатели на два разных объекта?
Чую беды от семантики перемещения

Comment: @rekrut1 Встречаю такую информацию, что после вызова move-присваивания, вектор-оригинал находится в неопределенном состоянии. Попробуй воспользоваться std::copy.

Comment: Не могу скрин из отладчика скинуть Вам.(

Comment: Неа.
copy тоже не помогает.

Comment: @rekrut1 а edges[i] всегда валиден? Попробуйте заменить на edges.at(i) . Если он выйдет за границы, то будет иключение std::out_of_range

Comment: вот, посмотрите http://fastpic.ru/view/33/2014/0218/31d41f1c2bd51681a9eebc4ef618cbec.png.html

Comment: @rekrut1 настаиваю попробовать с at. Больше реалистичных вариантов я не вижу: в один прекрасный i, edge[i] указывает черт знает куда, find его не находит, возвращает закрайний итератор, который вы пытаетесь удалить. Бам. Ошибка.

Comment: @rekrut1, нет, сглупил, по адресам действительно видно.